# Why do I see duplicates when querying these 3 tables?

Tags: mysql

I have the following schema with only relevant columns shown:

```
Table 1 - Metainfo
attrName
attrValue
instanceId

Table 2 - PrimaryData
attrName
attrValue
metaInstanceId

Table 3 - AuditData
result
metaInstanceId
```

In Metainfo, one row is attrName='timestamp' and attrValue='2012-01-01 12:00:01'.  There are multiple rows like this with different timestamps and therefore different instanceIds.  The table contains other metainformation we aren't interested in for my question as well, like hostnames.

My query is based on this timestamp attribute.  I want to join all 3 tables together via unique timestamps.  I tried this first:

```
SELECT meta.attrValue AS metaval, p.attrName AS configname, p.attrValue AS configvalue,      
       a.result AS auditresult FROM Metainfo meta 
                                    INNER JOIN PrimaryData p
                                        ON meta.instanceId = p.metaInstanceId 
                                    INNER JOIN AuditData a 
                                        ON meta.instanceId = a.metaInstanceId 
                                    WHERE meta.attrName='timestamp' 
                                    ORDER BY configname, metaval;
```

I think this gave me duplicate results because Metainfo to PrimaryData is a many to many relationship, then that result table joined with AuditData finally results to an even hairier many to many relationship.  So then I tried this:

```
SELECT m.attrValue AS metaval, p.attrName AS configname, p.attrValue AS configvalue,  
       a.result AS auditresult FROM Metainfo m, PrimaryData p, AuditData a 
                                    WHERE m.attrName='timestamp' AND  
                                    m.instanceId=p.metaInstanceId=a.metaInstanceId  
                                    ORDER BY configname, metaval;
```

I don't understand why this STILL gives me duplicates.  I think I'm saying, "get individual columns from 3 tables that deal with the timestamp metainfo, then group them first by configuration name, then by timestamp".

```
***TABLE Metainfo:***
*attrName    attrValue                               instanceId*
host        https://www.site1.com                   1
timestamp   2013-08-02 16:04:20.142                 1
host        https://www.site2.com                   2
timestamp   2013-08-05 01:00:11.001                 2
host        https://www.site3.com                   3
timestamp   2013-08-05 02:09:01.782                 3

**TABLE PrimaryData:**
*attrName        attrValue        metaInstanceId*
portNum         80                1
serverName      pegasus           1
inUse           F                 1
portNum         400               2
serverName      hercules          2
inUse           T                 2
portNum         4040              3
serverName      colossus          3
inUse           T                 3

**TABLE AuditData**
*result          metaInstanceId*
Pass             1
Pass             1
Fail             1
Pass             2
Pass             2
Pass             2
Fail             3
Pass             3
Pass             3
```

each row in AuditData tells us whether a configuration in PrimaryData passed or failed some test.  There are 3 configurations tested 3 times, which is why PrimaryData and AuditData have 9 rows.  Each of these tables has columns I haven't shown to make things easier.  I want a query that gives me the timestamp value, the configuration name, the configuration value, and the result.  So in the sample data shown this query would result in:

```
timestampVal                configName    configValue    result
2013-08-02 16:04:20.142     portNum       80             Pass
2013-08-05 01:00:11.001     portNum       400            Pass
2013-08-05 02:09:01.782     portNum       4040           Fail
2013-08-02 16:04:20.142     serverName    pegasus        Pass
2013-08-05 01:00:11.00      serverName    hercules       Pass
2013-08-05 02:09:01.782     serverName    colossus       Pass
2013-08-02 16:04:20.142     inUse         F              Fail
2013-08-05 01:00:11.001     inUse         T              Pass
2013-08-05 02:09:01.782     inUse         T              Pass
```

Comment: it seems like you order, not group.

Comment: Why don't you use `select distinct...`? That won't give you duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

you should consider `GROUP BY`

```
    WHERE meta.attrName='timestamp' 
    GROUP BY metaval
    ORDER BY configname, metaval;
```

or use the column which you dont want duplicates in group by

Comment: I did that and it shows me one row per timestamp, but those rows all deal with the first configuration.  I want it for all the configurations.  So if there are 3 configurations(configname, configval) and 4 timestamps(metaval), this resultset should hold 12 rows.

Comment: better show sample data and your wished result. to understand you good